# Adobe Fireworks: Crop Outside Canvas

Tags: canvas, adobe, shapes, fireworks

I'm doing some design work in Fireworks. I have my canvas set o the size I need it to be when I'm done (540x65), and have created a few shapes.

One of my shapes, a star, sits at (-8, -7) because I want it cut off in the top-left corner.

Is there any way to cut the shape off at the canvas mark (so I end up with a partial star at (0, 0)? Neither Trim Canvas nor Fit Canvas are correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, here's how I would accomplish this. In the images below, the light gray background is the FW canvas.

First, use the rectangle tool (`U`) to create a square large enough to cover your star:

[image: step 1 - create rectangle]

Next, drag the rectangle to (0, 0) and make sure it's on top of the star (`Modify -> Arrange -> Bring to Front`, if necessary):

[image: step 2 - overlay rectangle on star]

Finally, select both shapes and do `Modify -> Combine Paths -> Crop`. Since the rectangle was on top, this will crop the star to the boundaries of the rectangle:

[image: step 3 - crop]